# Getting repeated messages from a company in Developer Jobs section (bug?)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I asked a question of a company in Developer Jobs and they replied... and then the same reply keeps appearing every hour or so in my inbox. I've received 9 copies so far. I mentioned it in a reply to them after reply 7, but no word from them about it.

It's not a problem for me, but I'm curious if this is a bug in the message system, and I also don't know a better place to report a potential bug (I could flag the message as "something else", but that'd have the unwanted side effect of blocking that employer from sending me other sorts of messages...).

(I put the "bug" tag even though the tag description says it's for reproducible bugs, because I see no other tags that say they are about possible bugs.)

Comment: Tangentially related -- is there a [tag:feature-request] to allow flagging without blocking? Precisely for situations like this, where you need to bring a a mod's (or dev's) attention to something, but it's not bad on their part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. We had a deadlock occurring because of a synchronous wait on a `Task`. Doing so in a web app is a very bad thing :/. For now we've added a synchronous code path (in addition to the asynchronous one) and deployed the fix to production.

Apologies for the duplicate messages.

Comment: Thanks Dean! No worries, as it has near-zero impact on me to get them. Though, I note you posted this 12 hours ago, and according to my Inbox, I got the latest repeated message 9 hours ago. :-)